# How to convert string "req.body" to data (function)?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I make a function checkCompanyPermit with paramater companyIdSource and array allowed.

Example:

```
companyIdSouce: "req.body.companyId", "req.params.companyId"...
allowed: "user", "admin"...
```

With parameter companyIdSource as string, I want to convert it to data. It's worked if I use `eval(companyIdSource)` but it's bad. How can I do another?

I try use `Function("return " + companyIdSource)()` but it return an error: req is not defined.

```
const checkCompanyPermit = (companyIdSource, ...allowed) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const companyId = eval(companyIdSource) //Bad code, change another code
            const company = await Company.findById(companyId)
            //... some code
        } catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    }
}

checkCompanyPermit("req.body.companyId", "manager")
```

Comment: why this is string `"req.body.companyId"`. why can't you pass `req` and `res`

Comment: I write it in middleware, such as: router.put('/update',
    authentication.required,
    checkCompanyPermit("req.body.companyId", "manager"),
    companyController.update
)

Comment: There is something called express generator which generates a default structure which you can use for your project. Use it and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have access to the `req` object in your middleware, there is no need to pass the full string representation for `req.body.companyId`, just the property you need to check will suffice. Use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to access the value from req.body object i.e.

```
const checkCompanyPermit = (companyIdSource, allowed) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const companyId = req.body[companyIdSource]
            const company = await Company.findById(companyId)
            //... some code
        } catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    }
}

checkCompanyPermit("companyId", "manager")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Working For You.

```
    const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;

    const checkCompanyPermit = (companyIdSource, ...allowed) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const companyId = ObjectId('companyIdSource') //Replace here new code
            const company = await Company.findById(companyId)
            //... some code
        } catch (error) {
            next(error)
        }
    }
}

checkCompanyPermit("req.body.companyId", "manager")
```

Comment: Oh no, I use mongoose npm. Is there any way?

Comment: Ya, It's Working Fine with mongoose npm just try once.